# Sender, SenderEmailAddress Missing in Folder.Items

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I want to download attachments from Outlook emails.

Here is the code I am using to retrieve emails.

```
Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
Set OutlookNamespace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Folder = OutlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders(botMailFolder)

i = 1

For Each OutlookMail In Folder.Items
    If InStr(OutlookMail.Subject, " ") <> 0 Then

        If OutlookMail.Attachments.Count > 0 Then

            Dim folderBase As String
            folderBase = botLocalFolder

            Dim newFolder As String
            newFolder = folderBase & OutlookMail.EntryID

            'OutlookItem.SenderAddress

            If Not FolderExists(newFolder) Then
                FolderCreate newFolder
            End If

            For Each a In OutlookMail.Attachments
                Dim newFileName As String
                newFileName = newFolder & "\" & a.DisplayName
                'MsgBox newFileName
                a.SaveAsFile newFileName
            Next

        End If

    End If

Next OutlookMail
```

The problem is, `Sender`,`SenderEmailAddress` and `SenderName` are empty. Only `SenderEmailType` is populated as **EX**.

The code is executed as an Excel macro and all my senders (users) are Exchange 2013 users.

How can I find email address and name for the sender of an email item?

Here is what I see on my locals window.
[image: Locals window capture]

This happens for all emails in the box. Someone told me it is because all are "exchange users" and for them enterprise admins can put restrictions.

Comment: Can't see any code referring to the sender. Have you tried Ron de Bruin? https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/saveatt.htm

Comment: Does that happen for all items in that folder? Or just some? Do yo use the same problem in OutlookSpy if you click  the Item button?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko yes, for all emails in the box. Someone told me it is because all are "exchange users" and for them enterprise admins can put restrictions

Comment: @SJR I had ro comment the line as it is throwing error `'OutlookItem.SenderAddress`

Comment: What do you see in OutlookSpy?

Comment: I am sorry @DmitryStreblechenko, I am working for a company where OutlookSpy is not yet available as a developer tool.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue as well. The only way I could get past it is by running the code IN OUTLOOK VBA (Outlook -> developer tab -> vba), and do not start your application specifically as an outlook application.

example:

```
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Set olApp = CreateObject(Outlook.Application)
```

would need to become

```
Dim olApp As Application
Set olApp = Application
```

The trick is to NOT open a new instance of outlook from outside outlook (IE. in Excel). If you've got any type of Outlook Exchange security settings, opening outlook from excel will prohibit you from accessing key pieces of information such as sender.

Comment: I assume that even changing olApp As Application will still not make it work from outside Outlook VBA? (ie Excel)