# I want to read SenderAddress from office 365 Outlook mail using VBA in excel?

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I have tried everything to read a mail from office 365 outlook but I am not able to read it. Every time Sender address is coming empty.
Error That I am getting is :
Run-time error: ‘287’
Application-defined or object-defined error.

Please find the code that I am using.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Mail()

    Dim xNameSpace As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim xFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim xOutlookApp As Outlook.Application
    
    Set xOutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set xNameSpace = xOutlookApp.Session
    Set xFolder = xNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    
    Set xFolder = xFolder.Folders("Retail")
        ' Set Outlook application object.
    Dim objOutlook As Object
    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    
    Dim objNSpace As Object     ' Create and Set a NameSpace OBJECT.
    ' The GetNameSpace() method will represent a specified Namespace.
    Set objNSpace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    
    Dim myFolder As Object  ' Create a folder object.
    Set myFolder = objNSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    
    Dim objItem As Object
    Dim iRows, iCols As Integer
    iRows = 2

    ' Loop through each item in the folder.
    For Each objItem In xFolder.Items
        If objItem.Class = olMail Then
            Dim GetSenderAddress As String
            
            Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
            Set objMail = objItem
            
            Dim mailType As String
            mailType = objMail.SenderEmailType
            
            
            If mailType = "EX" Then
                ' GetSenderAddress = GetExchangeSenderAddressNew(objMail)
                FindAddress (objMail.SenderEmailAddress)
            Else
                GetSenderAddress = objMail.SenderEmailAddress
            End If

            Cells(iRows, 1) = objMail.SenderEmailAddress
            Cells(iRows, 2) = objMail.To
            Cells(iRows, 3) = objMail.Subject
            Cells(iRows, 4) = objMail.ReceivedTime
        End If
        iRows = iRows + 1
    Next
    Set objMail = Nothing
   
    ' Release.
    Set objOutlook = Nothing
    Set objNSpace = Nothing
    Set myFolder = Nothing

End Sub

Private Function GetExchangeSenderAddress(objMsg As MailItem) As String
    
    Dim oSession As Object
    Set oSession = CreateObject("MAPI.Session")
    oSession.Logon "", "", False, False
    
    Dim sEntryID As String
    Dim sStoreID As String
    Dim oCdoMsg As Object
    Dim sAddress As String
    Const g_PR_SMTP_ADDRESS_W = &H39FE001F
    
    sEntryID = objMsg.EntryID
    sStoreID = objMsg.Parent.StoreID
    Set oCdoMsg = oSession.GetMessage(sEntryID, sStoreID)
    
    sAddress = oCdoMsg.Sender.Fields(g_PR_SMTP_ADDRESS_W).Value
    Set oCdoMsg = Nothing
    oSession.Logoff
    Set oSession = Nothing
    
    GetExchangeSenderAddress = sAddress
    
End Function
```

Another Code is:

```
Sub Mail()

    Dim jsObj As New ScriptControl
    
    jsObj.Language = "JScript"
    
    With jsObj
        .AddCode "outlookApp = new ActiveXObject('Outlook.Application'); nameSpace = outlookApp.getNameSpace('MAPI'); nameSpace.logon('','',false,false); mailFolder = nameSpace.getDefaultFolder(6); var Inbox = mailFolder.Folders; var box = Inbox.Item('Retail').Items;  "
    End With
    
    
End Sub
```

Please let me know if i can read sender address of a mail in office 365 outlook.

Comment: Did you try to run the code under the debugger? Which line of code exactly gives the error message?

Comment: Outlook data not being available in through Excel has been described before. For example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52776954/sender-senderemailaddress-missing-in-folder-items Try retrieving data with Outlook VBA then pass the data to Excel.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the following lines of code iterates over all items in the folder:

```
' Loop through each item in the folder.
For Each objItem In xFolder.Items
    If objItem.Class = olMail Then
```

Where you don't check whether it is received or composed item. Composed emails may not have the Sender-related properties set yet, so you can use the [CurrentUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.currentuser) property which returns the display name of the currently logged-on user as a `Recipient` object.

Note, in case of Exchange accounts configured you may use the [AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.addressentry.getexchangeuser) property which returns an `ExchangeUser` object that represents the `AddressEntry` if the `AddressEntry` belongs to an Exchange `AddressList` object such as the Global Address List (GAL) and corresponds to an Exchange user.

The [ExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.exchangeuser.primarysmtpaddress) property returns a string representing the primary Simple Mail Transfer Protocol (SMTP) address for the ExchangeUser.

Comment: Still I am getting same error : Run-time error: ‘287’ Application-defined or object-defined error.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Which line of code exactly gives the error message?

Comment: objMail.SenderEmailAddress this is the property that is giving me error