# Application defined problem Outlook export to excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have `Application defined or Object defined` error at the part where I want to retrieve the mail content in Outlook. Here is my code

```
Sub Import_Outlook_to_Excel()
    Dim oitem As outlook.MailItem
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Body As String
    Dim olapp As outlook.Application
    Dim olappns As outlook.Namespace
    Dim oinbox As outlook.Folder
    Dim oFolder As outlook.MAPIFolder

    i = 2    outlook
    Set olapp = New outlook.Application
    Set olappns = olapp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set oinbox = olappns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Winautomation")

    For Each oitem In oinbox.Items
        Sheets(1).Cells(i, 5).Value = oitem.Subject
        Sheets(1).Cells(i, 6).Value = oitem.Body
        i = i + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: which line you are getting error.

Comment: `i = 2 outlook` should be `i = 2`

Comment: Works Ok for me unless I do not have a winautomation sub folder of inbox .... after i=2 outlook line is fixed

Comment: This part works; "Sheets(1).Cells(i, 5).Value = oitem.Subject" And This Part does not Work; " Sheets(1).Cells(i, 6).Value = oitem.Body", so it might be some sort of security issue.

Comment: "i = 2 outlook" was my mistake when printing the code above,

Comment: Same question (without solution) there: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43761831/10908769

Comment: ... and many ideas (please check), but maybe again no solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17065844/10908769

Comment: Thanks everyone, what I've read and heard is that win 10 does not support this which is kind of annoying